# Remove NodeJS http2 default headers / get them in right order

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do a http2 request and I'm using the http2 library from nodejs.

```
var body = {
      query: 'query',
      variables: null,
      operationName: "",
    };

    const client = http2.connect("https://host", {
      createConnection: () =>
        tls.connect({
          host: "host",
          socket: socket,
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          ALPNProtocols: ["h2"],
        }),
    });

    const req = client.request({
      ":method": "POST",
      ":authority": "host",
      ":scheme": "https",
      ":path": "/path/",
    });

    var headers =
      "accept: application/json";

    const buffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body));
    var payload = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(headers, "utf8"), buffer]);

    req.setEncoding("utf8");
    let data = [];
    req.on("data", (chunk) => {
      data.push(chunk);
    });
    req.write(payload);

    req.end();
    req.on("end", () => {
      console.log(data.join());
    });
  });
```

This is my test request. I've inspected the request with Charles Proxy and I found out that it probably fails, because the target server checks the order of the headers. In my header object, they're in the right order, but they get sent in a different order. This is the only difference to the original request, which works.

Is there any way to
a) disable them and send them manually with the rest of the headers or
b) get them sent in the correct order?

If I just don't define them in the header object they default to ":path": "/" and ":method": "get".